# What is the general flow of the type inference algorithm in these cases where there is very little type information?

Tags: type-theory, type-inference

For a state of the art compiler, can they successfully do type inference on all of these cases, or are there some in which they can't? If there is a place which collects a bunch of test cases which a compiler should handle, please let me know, that would be wonderfully useful in building a compiler, and would also probably answer this question.

Assume some parser can convert this pseudo code into an AST, and the type inference algorithm works on that. The simple cases are where the types are defined. So I am going to focus on the cases where they are mostly not.

*Note: I have read around many different papers in searching for type inference algorithms, but haven't found anything really close to implementation details, hence this question.*

### Cases

For each case, what should type inference do? I wanted to ask this to get started on how to make a type inference algorithm. If you could describe briefly what the type inference thing would do (where it starts and ends in processing the code), that would be it.

If it's easier to just summarize all the cases rather than specifying each one individually, that works too.

#### Case 1

Can it tell that `fun_a` needs to be typed as integers, given that we have never called `fun_a`, but there is the `* 2`? What is the general flow of the type inference algorithm?

```
function fun_a(x, y) {
  return fun_b(x, y) + fun_b(y, x)
}

function fun_b(x, y) {
  return (x + y) * 2
}
```

#### Case 2

How about if we call it? What does it do in this case?

```
fun_a(1, 3)

function fun_a(x, y) {
  return fun_b(x, y) + fun_b(y, x)
}

function fun_b(x, y) {
  return (x + y) * 2
}
```

#### Case 3

I know a type inference algorithm (like [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)) can handle this one, where it has a condition before calling the numbers:

```
function fun_a(x, y) {
  if (x is number && y is number) {
    return fun_b(x, y) + fun_b(y, x)
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}

function fun_b(x, y) {
  return (x + y) * 2
}
```

There I assume it starts with `fun_a(x` and then slowly it adds type info to it when it encounters the `number` condition, then inside that it passes those types down, and then infers that the `fun_b` types must be numbers?

#### Case 4

In this case, there is no number anywhere, so what would it do? + could mean addition of numbers, or concat of strings perhaps. How should it then type these?

```
function fun_a(x, y) {
  return fun_b(x, y) + fun_b(y, x)
}

function fun_b(x, y) {
  return x + y
}
```

#### Case 5

```
function fun_a(x: number, y) {
  return fun_b(x, y) + fun_b(y, x)
}

function fun_b(x, y) {
  return x + y
}
```

#### Case 6

In this case it seems it could figure out the type of everything, but it would have to work backwards maybe (from `fun_b` return to `fun_a` inputs)?

```
function fun_a(x, y) {
  return fun_b(x, y) + fun_b(y, x)
}

function fun_b(x, y): number {
  return x + y
}
```

### Summary

In summary, these cases hint at how the possibility of what a compiler type inference algorithm could solve for, and the order of operations. But there are probably many more cases I missed. If there is a resource which describes this sort of thing well (the cases and how to handle it), please let me know.

In particular I am interested in *imperative languages* (like typescript, or rust). I am working on a custom imperative programming language and would like to know how to start solving for the various cases type inference will face, given that there will be minimal requirement to specify types explicitly (ideally like [lobster](https://strlen.com/lobster/)).

Comment: I guess it might help if I study something like [julia's typeinf algorithm](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/ae55fb22168cc5c0496b3a12217c84e7558dbb43/base/compiler/typeinfer.jl#L844), though knowing test cases like I've described would be even better. _(I don't know julia yet)_

Comment: As I said in another answer, there are good textbooks about PL that I would recommend looking at. The things you are asking are not explainable in a short answer, it takes some background reading. Another resource is [OPLSS](https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer21/) which has a ton of material and videos. If you rummage a bit you might find what you're looking for. (For instance, the [OPLSS 2017](https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer17/topics.php) has "Background in PL" but I am not sure what was covered.)

Comment: The answer for every case is probably "It depends on the language, the type system, the type inference algorithm, and the compiler".